# How to convert a boost::filesystem::directory_iterator to a const char *

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I want to iterate over all the files in a directory and print their contents.
Boost handles the iteration part very nicely but I have no idea how to conver that into a `const char *`.

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator path_it(path);
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_it;
    while(path_it != end_it){
      std::cout << *path_it << std::endl;

      // Convert this to a c_string
      std::ifstream infile(*path_it);
    }
```

I tried to read this [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator) but couldn't find anything like `string` or `c_str()`. I'm new to both `C++` and `boost` and was hoping to find some `javadoc` like documentation which would basically tell me what the members were and what functions were availabe instead of dumping the source code.

Sorry for the rant but could someone tell me how to convert `*path_it` into a `c string`.

Comment: It's in [directory_entry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_entry).

Comment: Thanks, figured it out from this. Any tips on how I can learn boost in a less painful way?

Comment: I think your best bet is to try and find unit tests. Or write them yourself to figure stuff out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you dereference the iterator it returns a `directory_entry`:

```
const directory_entry& entry = *path_it;
```

You can use this along with `operator<<` and `ostream`, as you've discovered:

```
std::cout << entry << std::endl;
```

You could create a string using `ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;

oss << entry;

std::string path = oss.str();
```

Alternatively you can access the path as a `string` directly from `directory_entry`:

```
std::string path = entry.path().string();
```

Comment: Thanks for both the comment and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the documentation I think you can do `path_it->path().c_str()` since a `directory_iterator` iterates over `directory_entry` which has a `path()` function which in turn has a `c_str()` function.

Comment: I needed to do `path_it->path().string().c_str()` to get it to work.